# Ionic 3, erro ao instalar o app-script 1.3.0

Tags: ionic, npm

Complementando a pergunta anterior, Estou em um ambiente ionic 3, dou um npm install mas fica faltando esse app-script 1.3.0, msm instalando locamente o ionic 2, npm install novamente msm erro acredito que seja um 404, ai altero o package.json para app-script 2.0 ou 3.0 ai sim ele instala, mas ao dar ionic serve ele aparece a seguinte mensagem undefined webpack jsonp[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

amigo apesar de sua pergunta não está muito clara passei por este problema a um tempo atras quando fui reativar um velho projeto.

se for a mesma coisa eu acrescentei no arquivo index.html o trecho abaixo:

```
<script src="build/vendor.js"></script>
```

pois é no vendor.js onde é definido todos os módulos do node.

se realmente não funcionar tente executar no prompt de comando os comandos abaixo:

```
ionic cordova platform remove nomePlataforma
```

e em seguida o comando:

```
ionic cordova platform add nomePlataforma
```

após os comandos executados tente executar novamente.